# Can I prove this inequality?

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

For $0<e<1<d$ and $n>2$, how can I prove the following inequality (if, in fact, it's true / possible)?

$$\frac{4n+4e}{4+n^2+4e+e^2}>\frac{4nd^2+4de}{4d^2+n^2d^2+2nde+e^2}$$

I tried setting $d=1, n=2$ to test the behaviour just beyond the limit, and it then becomes

$$\frac{4n+4e}{4+n^2+4e+e^2}=\frac{4n+4e}{4+n^2+4e+e^2}$$

Various tables I created suggest that the inequality is true... But I'm stumped on how to actually prove it.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community.  In particular, what is the source of the inequality, and why is it of interest?

Comment: OK, if you need more context, then it will take me a while to write up. I think it may be easier to close this thread and start a new one.